# Adding another spatial DataBase in PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

Is there a way to add another Spatial DataBase in PostGIS in the same SERVER?

[image]

[image]

Becuse it gives me this ERROR, when i´m trying to do ...

[image]

---

I disconnected the DB postgis_23_Sample and create my new DB using advice from @Vesanto.

Comment: >kill the postgres sessions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108876/kill-a-postgresql-session-connection

Comment: Do you actually need the `postgis_23_template`? Usually if you need a fresh database, you don't need this. Templates were useful up until 2010, but they are not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a case of second (third ...) spatial database but as your error said your template database is in use.

Following [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html):

> The principal limitation is that no other sessions can be connected to
>   the source database while it is being copied.

Comment: So the way to solve the issue is to right-click on the postgis_23_template database and choose "Disconnect server". Although there may also be other users using it, based on "5 other sessions using it".